# What is the popper's business?

Tags: meaning

What is the popper's business? I don't know what the popper is.

I heard somewhere the phrase. "He's in popper's business."

please let me know:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it have been "he's in Papa's business", i.e. his father's business? In some places the diminutive is spelt (and pronounced) *Poppa*.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to:

**Popper:**

(Recreational Drugs) an amyl nitrite capsule, which is crushed and its contents inhaled by drug users as a stimulant

Source: Collins Dictionary

Popper business probably refers to dealing with this sort of drugs.

Comment: Is it some kind of slang?

Comment: I guess it is, like the many names that we hear every time a new drug becomes popular.